# Ubuntu 20.04 - How to Uninstall Davinci Resolve 17

Tags: davinci-resolve

After installing Davinci Resolve 17 last week on my Dell Precision 4600 Nvidia 1000M 2GB Graphics, I observed that the software was not detecting my GPU hardware; after some hacks, I was able to bypass that.

Now, a new issue came up, after editing a video, when I click on the Deliver tab; the app freezes immediately. After multiple efforts to resolve that, nothing worked, it continues to hang when I click on the **Deliver** tab.

Now I picked KDenLive and that seemed to work great.

My issue is now is:: How do I uninstall DaVinci Resolve, I actually installed it using the .run file and building a .deb install using MakeResolveDeb.

Comment: "I actually installed it using the .run file and building a .deb install using MakeResolveDeb." May we please see a link to the process you followed?

Comment: Thanks, I used the guide on this url
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/how-to-install-davinci-resolve-15-in.html

Comment: If you still have the .deb then just double-clicking it should open the Ubuntu Software and an option to uninstall. Then the rest can be deleted. There's no point in uninstalling the prerequisites (dependencies) because that take negligible space and may come in handy in the future.

Comment: The link to the script says: "Uninstall DaVinci Resolve: `sudo apt-get remove davinci-resolve` Did you try that? Were there any errors?

Comment: Thanks, I actually learned something better in the process. I figured a way to query an app in the system to identify the exact package name and then remove it using the normal uninstall command.

Comment: Please post it as an answer, accept it and we'll upvote it.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a terminal command for identifying the exact name of the application in the system app repo

+To query installed packages we can use powerful search functions from DPKG package management:

```
dpkg-query --list 'part_of_package_name*' lists all packages that have not been purged
```

That returned the exact name of the davinci-code application in the system, and then I used sudo apt-get remove app-name to remove the application.

Thanks all for your input.

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

$ Ctrl + T

to open the terminal

$ /opt/resolve/installer

then just follow the Uninstaller

for folks coming in the future who want an easy solution.